# Need help improving my horizontal scroller

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I created a horizontal scroll and I'm putting buttons in it so the user can scroll in any direction left/right.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


[self.scroller setScrollEnabled:YES]; 
[self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1300, 30)];

 }
```

This code lets the UIScrollview scroll horizontally but if you scroll in any direction you have to hold the scroller at all times or else if you let it go, it'll scroll back by itself where you originally started.

I want to make it that if the user scrolls to any direction and lets go of the scroller, that the scroller stays at this point as opposed to moving back by itself.

What can I add to the code to let the scroll stay where I scrolled it to as opposed to having it move back by itself as I let go the scroller?

Comment: in viewDidAppear what are the values for frame and contentSize of self.scroller?  If they are the same then that would be the problem.  Let me know what the values are for that

Comment: This is the only code I used for horizontal scrolling. In storyboards though, the width of the UIScrollView  is under 1300. I thought maybe there's an extra line of code that solves this issue.

Comment: I understand... how about you just print the values in viewDidAppear like I suggested so that you can debug where the issue is occurring. Also, are you using auto layout or adding anything to the scrollview in the storyboard? or is everything that is added to the scroll view done programmatically?

Comment: I use Auto Layout but I clicked on the UIScrollView and "clear constraints". I'm only adding action buttons on the UIScrollview.

Comment: Things get complicated when you mix Auto-layout with non-Auto-layout. If your view *is* using auto-layout, then the ContentSize of the scroll view is controlled by the constraints on the subviews contained by the scroll view. So, you manually set ContentSize to 1300x30, and as soon as the user scrolls, the constraints snap it back to where it was. Show your code where you are adding content to the scroll view -- that will make it easier to help.